# iBooks on El Capitan

Tags: macos, performance, books

I have a large number of items in iBooks. Some are ePub, and there are lots of work related PDFs. In total, I have around 20k documents that I want to sync to my iPad to carry around as a convenient source of reference.

Unfortunately I appear to have hit a limit with iBooks. I want to add another 1k docs. They import into iBooks successfully and initially they show in the UI however at some point the bkAgentService seems to have a brainstorm and the docs I can see in the UI and in iTunes reverts to what was there, so I lost the ability to access the most recent docs in either iBooks or iTunes.

Anyone any ideas on this? Also, bkAgentService takes up a LOT of CPU for some time when I open iBooks. Presumably it doesn't like the number of docs I have, though Apple says the size of the library is limited only by available storage?